# Swift / Action on UILabel Subclass, delegate method not called

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) to handle URLs in Labels. To open a `UIViewController` with a `WebView` to display URL's Content, I want to use a delegate method.

I have tried to different ways to debug my issue.

```
protocol ActiveLabelURLDelegate {
    func activeLabelURLDelegate(url: NSURL)
}

extension FirstVC: ActiveLabelURLDelegate {

    func activeLabelURLDelegate(url: NSURL) {

        print("debug activeLabelURLDelegate called") // THIS PRINT WILL NOT CALLED

        let vc = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! SecondVC

        vc.webSite = url        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: ActiveLabel!
    var labelURLDelegate : ActiveLabelURLDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() { 

         myLabel.handleURLTap { givenURL in
             print("Success. You just tapped the \(givenURL) URL") // THIS PRINT IS CALLED
             self.labelURLDelegate?.activeLabelURLDelegate(givenURL)
         }    
     } 
}
```

After this wasn't working I implemented a helping function to debug what is called.

```
func openURL(url: NSURL) {

    print("debug openURL called") // THIS PRINT IS CALLED AS WELL    
    labelURLDelegate?.activeLabelURLDelegate(url)
}
```

Called by:

```
myLabel.handleURLTap { givenURL in
    print("Success. You just tapped the \(givenURL) URL") // STILL CALLED
    self.openURL(givenURL)
}
```

As you can see on the print statements, everything works till the delegate call. The delegate function `activeLabelURLDelegate` is not called. What am I missing? In the same Cell and same `UIViewController`, I'm using 4 other delegates for `UIButtons` and they are working perfectly.

PS: Links will be correctly displayed as Links within the UI & the correct URL is printed to the console.

Comment: In my case -
 myLabel.handleURLTap { givenURL in print("Success. You just tapped the (givenURL) URL") // THIS PRINT IS NOT CALLED  }
 Can you suggest the reason for this?

Comment: Most likely the same reason. Delegate not hooked. Did you check for `myLabel.delegate = self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to hook up the delegate. I don't see an assignment to labelURLDelegate in your cell code.

Comment: A good rule of thumb: When code seems like it should work but doesn't, check your outlet and delegate connections.

Comment: Oh, and check IBAction connections too.

Comment: Yeah sure. checking that always first

Comment: can't believe that apple didn't made a system inside xcode that deletes references when the code gets deleted...